# How to store the temperature and corresponding time to a file through Shell?

Tags: linux, file, shell, terminal, sensors

My laptop is often getting heated up to high temperatures around 60-75 degree Celsius. I have installed `lm_sensors`. And I have found out few command to do that.I need to generate a file with the following parameters measured at every 1 minutes.

1. Measured value of temperature. It can be done by the command `sensors >> temperature.txt`
2. The time at which the temperature has measured. It can be done by `date >> temperature.txt`
3. The number of currently running processes `ps-aux` (But this won't give the **number** of processes).

I came to know that it is a task to be done with `shell scripts`(Is it ?). Can anybody suggest me a way to do that as I have only little idea about shell scripting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script itself could be something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

file=/your_home_dir/temp_info
temperature=$(sensors | tail -3)
when=$(date "+%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
working_proc=$(ps -aux | wc -l)

echo "$when num_proc: $working_proc" >> $file
echo "$temperature" >> $file
```

With output like

```
20130724_131150 num_proc: XXX
temp line1
temp line2
20130724_131250 num_proc: YYY
temp line1
temp line2
...
```

---

To have it calculated every 1 minute, you can use `crontab`:

Do `crontab -e` and add the following line:

```
* * * * * /bin/sh /path/to/script.sh 2>/dev/null
```

You can see more information about crontab in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/crontab/info. Basic ideas:

- With this expression `* * * * *`, `crontab` runs every minute, any day, any time.
- With `2>/dev/null` we avoid the hypothetical error messages to appear in the console. They are "targeted" to `/dev/null` so they do not appear. Idea: do `ls -l /hellooooo` and you will get an error message. Do `ls -l /helloooo 2>/dev/null` and you will not.

Comment: But the temperature information given by the `sensors` is lengthy one. But I need only the last two lines of the `sensors` output in my `file`. Any way to do that ?

Comment: @noufal, can you please post an example of `sensors` output? I guess that `temperature=$(sensors | tail -2)` may make it, but just to be sure.

Comment: two small corrections 1> temperature=$(sensors | tail `-3`) and 2>echo "$when num_proc: $workin`g`_proc" >> $file

Comment: Oh sure! Well seen. So now it must be working. Keep updated and remember you can mark as accepted if is done :)

Comment: Please see the output at http://tinypic.com/r/2drgyrs/5 and could you please elaborate more on `crontab` and `/bin/sh /path/to/script.sh 2>/dev/null`

Comment: thank you for the elaborated answer. I think I have learned something ! ! !